# Android Scroll View in fragment crops content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I created a Scroll View which should allow me to scroll through all the content which is inside Linear Layout (that is a child of Scroll View).

Code looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="pl.oakfusion.delegator.DomesticDelegationSecondFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ....

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@color/textDarkest"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Preview looks like this:

[image: Preview]

But in my app I have this:

[image: App portrait]

I can't scroll down, this is all I can see.

If I allow to rotate I have horizontal view:

[image: App horizontal]

which now allows me to scroll but cuts the button entirely. (On the picture is bottom of view) I can pull down fast and I can see that the button is there but it goes up again (this android thing when you can pull slightly further but it scrolls back)

How can I fix this?

Hosting activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="pl.oakfusion.delegator.DomesticDelegationActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: how your activity layout looks like (xml)? Do you use some CoordinatorLayout like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709100/how-to-use-coordinator-layout-with-fragment-as-scrolling-view ?

Comment: Kindly share your complete xml, and also hosting layout(if any) to rectify the issue.

Comment: Right, updating post

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the scrollView in your xml layout

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: And if you set it to false? For many people this should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem once. I tried adding padding for the ViewGroup inside ScrollView. Then it worked fine. Its a hacky solution and not an ideal one.

For the example mentioned above (by user3212350):
I have added some padding to the LinearLayout inside ScrollView to make the view completely visible. The amount of padding required may differ for various screen sizes.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="pl.oakfusion.delegator.DomesticDelegationSecondFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ##android:paddingBottom="50dp"##>

        ....

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@color/textDarkest"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add a piece of code to explain exactly how you didi it ?

Comment: @JosephBudin I have added some code for you to better understand how I solved the issue. Alternate solution is you can add a dummy textview at the end with text color same as background color (to make it invisible) to get the same effect. Again this is also a hacky solution and not an ideal one